# How to define global template variable in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have simple template with tabs which are switching controlers in template

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="tab = 1">Users</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" ng-click="tab = 2">Games</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab" ng-hide="tab != 1 && tab != null" users>...</div>
<div class="tab" ng-hide="tab != 2" games>...</div>
```

Everything work as expected, but in new update of dart editor variable "tab" is marked as "undefined name 'tab'"

Is it bug or i should initalize tab variable in some place (where?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK this is just the DartEditor not recognizing Angular expressions.
If it's just the underline and no exceptions or similar you can ignore it.

Maybe DartEditor is checking for Polymer-specific declarations here.
Better Angular support in DartEditor is work in progress.